# Implementation of long-polling in asynchronous web framework like twisted or klein

Tags: python-3.x, web-services, asynchronous, twisted, klein-mvc

I'm relatively new to REST API and web development in general. I'm looking for options for a client GET request to receive data incrementally/streaming until all data is sent with some criterias:

- Has to be async (need to use twisted/klein as framework), [here's only with Flask as reference.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/)
- Need to render server-side (next.js has option with socket.io in [here](https://github.com/sergiodxa/next-socket.io) with react -> which is the frontend I use), I know it's unrelated, but it's nice to have reading materials like that so I can glue/frankensteinize components together.

[image: my model]

From the server (python) It has to be yielded from generator object, right? what confusing me is the underlying options/quirks between websocket, long polling, and server-sent-events, not to mention frameworks like autobahn, WAMP and service like pushpin and crossbar.io which I *think* is overkill for my case.

The reason I'm mentioning them all is to ask for best practice in using them with their many ways of implementation (phew..). It's a bit overwhelming without enough experience.

At the core level (http headers/protocols/curl), what need to be actually set on the client and server given my scenario? And does long polling sounds like the solution? Does async is a good idea?

Reference reading:

[What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

[My Understanding of HTTP Polling, Long Polling, HTTP Streaming and WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555043/my-understanding-of-http-polling-long-polling-http-streaming-and-websockets)

http://blog.fanout.io/2016/11/21/moving-from-polling-to-long-polling/

https://blog.al4.co.nz/2016/01/streaming-json-with-flask/

**TL;DR: Best practice of long polling implementation in asynchronous python webserver.**

Comment: Nevow Athena (based on Twisted Web) uses essentially the low-level technique you describe here to provide a high-level bi-directional symmetric RPC system.  It's a fairly obscure library, though, and you may have difficulty finding a supporting community for it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it, it's in the documentation the whole time (twisted web), should've looked there first.